# Телеграм прерывает соединение с ботами

Tags: c#, python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Здравствуйте! Написал 2х ботов, на С# (Robin Telegram API) и Python (Telebot). Проблема в том, что со временем (несколько дней) боты падают.
Ошибки на скриншотах. Боты совершенно разные.[image: C# Bot Error]
[image: Python Bot Error]

Comment: В чем проблема переподключиться?

Comment: @AndrioSkur проблемы в этом нет, но всё же, нужна стабильная работа.

Comment: ИМХО стабильная работа как раз и достигается за счет возможности самоустранения мелких неисправностей (тем более если дело касается внешних факторов таких как доступ в интернет). Обработайте исключение, добавьте лог, чтобы знать когда это происходит. Например VK около 6:00 несколько секунд тоже недоступен (во всяком случае у меня).

Comment: @eblomyac как вариант, сделал цикл, который будет пытаться запустить воскресить бота, пока он не перестанет бросать исключения. Но стоит ли такое делать. Хм.

Comment: юзаете getUpdates? *try catch* в помощь,
хотите стабильности - юзайте вебхуки